# How to $watch for changes to a list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_nth/HEzxZ/7/)

I have a list, and I'd like to be notified whenever it changes. A simple `$watch` expression isn't working, which I'm guessing is because angular is checking for referential equality, not structural equality.

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Root">
        <h1>Base Angular Fiddle</h1>
        Times changed: {{timesChanged}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
            <li><button ng-click="names.push('another name')">Add</button></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
​

​function Root($scope) {
    $scope.timesChanged = 0;
    $scope.names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    $scope.$watch('names', function() {
        $scope.timesChanged++;
    });
}​
```

What I'm hoping will happen is that the callback for `'names'` is called each time that I call `names.push()`. Is there a workaround that's recommended for this? Or am I just not using `$watch` correctly?

Comment: You may have posted the wrong fiddle version. There is no code in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have this code - can you update?

Comment: Yep, I definitely posted the wrong version - sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, angular checks for reference by default, for perfomance reasons. The usage of reference vs equality depends on the value of the $watch function's third argument, as you can see [in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch). Just set it to true (it is false by default) and your fiddle will work - [here it is, working.](http://jsfiddle.net/HEzxZ/1/)

the change:

```
$scope.$watch('names', function() {
        $scope.timesChanged++;
    }, true);
```

EDIT - Performance implications:

Comparing two arrays/objects can obviously be very inefficient (hence the check by reference angular makes by default), depending on the size and complexity of your variables. There is an alternate method - watching the length of the array. This has obvious limitations - changing one element no longer triggers the $watch function - but can be immensely faster. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEzxZ/8/)!

Comment: yeah, I considered doing a `$watch` on `names.length`, but then you're right that it wouldn't fire when an element changes without changing the length.

Comment: yup, and I just updated my updated fiddle, to illustrate that to any who stumble upon this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick addition:

If you want to watch for more *special* things you can do it like so:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    // Define what you are watching for
    // For example convert your array into a string
    return String($scope.names);
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // Do something cool.
});
```

This is definitely not as fast as `names.length` but you could play around and find a sophisticating solution.

If anyone is interested I played around a bit with fast hashing that uses a modified Duff's device: http://jsfiddle.net/flek/mfKT6/1/ If you are dealing with massive data this hashing method could also be updated to be error responsive (like hash only every 2nd or 3rd character)